# Release camera when other app requires it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am building an app that uses the camera's flashlight. To do this it has to acquire the camera with `camera.open()` which gives me control of the device's camera until I release it.

The problem comes when a user tries to open another app that uses the camera, such as the default Camera app. If my app is running it gives a `Can't connect to the camera.` error which is frustrating and potentially a little confusing for the user. I don't want to hog the camera, just use the flashlight if no other app is using it.

From my research it looks unlikely but does anyone know of a way to hook a camera request from another app so that I can release my hold on it immediately?

Comment: u need a flash light or the camera ? in the background service

Answer (score 0):

Acquire camera only between `onStart` and `onStop` of your `Activity`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am acquiring the camera in an unbound background service as I want the user to be able to do other stuff whilst using the flashlight.